# Can I archive an entire organization on Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-organization

I am the admin for a number of organizations that I set up for specific, not very long term, projects. I don't want to see some of these organizations any more, but I don't want to lose their data. Can they be archived?

Answer (score 1):

SteB's answer is right, but I think you'll find it helpful to know that after you delete the organization you can still view the boards by clicking the `Boards` menu on the top right by your profile pic and then click `View Closed Boards` at the bottom of the menu. You'll find your all your boards are available even though you deleted the organization they were associated with.

When you re-open the board it will show up in your My Boards list.

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot archive an organization, you can only delete an organization or set it's visibility to private.